# How to convert this firebase code into its latest syntax in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
  });
}, []);
```

I have been trying to use this code in react but I was unable to do it.

Comment: can anyone correct it according to the latest syntax of Firebase??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9)

```
import { doc, onSnapshot, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
db = getFirestore();

const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "cities", "SF"), (doc) => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Comment: what is "SF" here??

Comment: in your instance, `doc(db, 'posts')` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc